# Spring REST URI: How to differentiate b/w user and admin

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-rest

I am a bit confused and need help in understanding the way I can define my REST URI for users.

Requirement: I wanted to achieve something like below:

1. GET URI: /users/me/addresses: This API will be invoked by client only(iOS). The user detail will be fetched from auth token and the returned object will exclude some of the fields.
2. GET URI: /users/{userId}/addresses: This API will be invoked by customer care WEB portal and the returned object will have all the fields

To achieve this I exposed two methods one with URI '/users/me/addresses' and other with '/users/{userId}/addresses'. However seems Spring consider both of the API as same and doesn't allow that. So I am looking for an alternative approach to achieve my goal.

Comment: Sounds like a bad solution. What if you had a userId of 'me'? Consider passing `userId` in a header or in the method checking if the user is a customer care agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regexp to make spring consider the two mappings as different. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex).

```
@RequestMapping("/users/{userId:\\d+}/addresses")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure how that will solve the issue. Spring will still consider both the API as same

Comment: No, it won't. That's the whole point. Because /users/me/addresses doesn't match `/users/{userId:\\d+}/addresses` anymore. It matched `/users/{userId}/addresses` though.